# finding the average rate for a changing probability

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I want to find an average rate for a changing probability: the probability for A is 1/420 but the probability doubled after you reach 420 tries without getting A yet, if you get A the counter will reset and the chance will back to 1/420 and it will be doubled if you didn't get A in the next 420 tries (if you got A in try number 100 for example the counter will back to 0), first I tried to get how many tries I need to do for a 99% chance to get A, I tried several equation and I came up with this [(419/420)^420 * (418/420)^(x-420) = 0.01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUkX0.png)

while 0.01 is the chance of not getting it in x tries, now I want calculate the average of how many times I get A per tries, the answer is indeed more than 1 time per 420 tries, but I have no idea how to calculate it, or if there is a law for questions like this.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Your question is hard to read because it seems like you're using 'x' for several things: “success” in one of these dependent trials, and also the number of trials needed for the probability of at least one success to exceed 0.95.  If I'm right, please consider rewriting the question to clarify.

Comment: I changed it, thank you for the tip, I hope it's more clearly to understand now.